# Weak Kodaira Vanishing - Hartshorne III.7.1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

In the Serre Duality section of *Algebraic Geometry* by Robin Hartshorne, the following exercise is posed: If $X$ is an integral projective scheme over a field $k$, prove that an ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal L$ is such that $\mathcal L^{-1}$ has no nonzero global sections. This is fairly straightforward when there are additional hypotheses on $X$ (for example, those that let you use Theorem 7.6b), but in the stated generality I'm not sure what to do. I can reduce to the case of $\mathcal L$ very ample, but that's about as far as I get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can show that, for $n\gg0$, $\mathcal L^n$ has a lot of global sections. ($\dim_k(H^0(X,\mathcal L^n))\geq \dim X+1$).

If $\mathcal L^{-1}$ has a nonzero global section, then so does $\mathcal L^{-n}$. Tensor these with those of $\mathcal L^n$ to get lots of global sections of $\mathcal{O}_X$. But we know there is only one global section (up to scalar of course).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was trying to use Serre duality and Ext (since those are the nearby concepts), but I guess the proof is just elementary.

Comment: But why $L^n$ has a lot of global sections?

Comment: Do you mean that, after tensoring a nonzero global section of $L^{-n}$, the image must have dimension more than 1? Why? I have no ideal how to deal with the difference between $H^0(X, L^{n}) \otimes H^0(X, L^{-n})$ and $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$.

Answer (score 2):

Similar with the above answer. (But I cannot add a comment?)

Since $\mathscr{L}$ is ample, we just pick an $n$ such that $\mathscr{L}^{n}$ is very ample, and $\dim_{k}(H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{n}))=\dim X+1$. If $\mathscr{L}^{-1}$ has a nonzero global section $s$, the morphism $H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{n})\rightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathscr{O}_{X})$ as $\times s^{n}$ has image more than dimension one, which makes a contradiction.

Comment: I don't see why the map $H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{n})\rightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathscr{O}_{X})$ is injective. 
I can define an injective map
$$H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes n}) \longrightarrow H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes n}) \otimes_k 
H^{0}\left(X,\mathscr{L}^{-1}\right)^{\otimes n},  \qquad x \mapsto x \otimes s^{\otimes n}$$
But the natural map 
$$
H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{\otimes n}) \otimes_k 
H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{-1})^{\otimes n} \longrightarrow
H^0(X, \mathscr{L}^{\otimes n} \otimes {(\mathscr{L}^{-1})}^{\otimes n}) \cong H^0(X,O_X)$$
is not known to be injective.

Comment: However, the composition $H^0(X, L^{\otimes n}) \to H^0(X, O_X)$ should be injective by composing further with $H^0(X, O_X) \to O_{X,p}$ for a point $p$ such that $s$ doesn't vanish at $p$.

Comment: How can you get the equality $\dim_{k}(H^{0}(X,\mathscr{L}^{n}))=\dim X+1$ ?